# How I get a by name a property of an System.Object

Tags: c#

I have an object of type `Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models.EventGridEvent`. It has a property named `Data` of type `System.Object`. I want to access the value of the `itemId` property of `Data`. How do I get the value of a System.Object property?

Comment: Do you know the actual type of that object, not just the declaration type?

Comment: Those are the actual types.

Comment: If it really is a `System.Object` (instantiated like `new Object()`), then it does not have an `itemId`. It must be some subclass of `Object`. If you know the actual subclass (or anything in the inheritance tree that has the `itemId`), then you can just cast to that type. Otherwise, see nvoigt's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Object` has no properties. However, assuming that there is another object derived from `object` (so basically any object) you can access it's properties by name using the `dynamic` keyword:

```
Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models.EventGridEvent event = GetEvent(); 
dynamic data = event.Data;
dynamic itemId = data.itemId;
```

However, I would recommend you look for the proper classes and datatypes, that is much safer and easier than guessing and seeing whether it works at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You have to down cast to the actual type of the object. Since you know the type of the object that you expect, this should work in most cases, but I recommend you have some error handling to detect the case where some code has set the value of `Data` to a type you didn't expect, or to null. Personally I like to do checked downcasts with the `as` operator, because I find that concise, so something like this:

```
int GetItemId(EventGridEvent ev)
{
    T dt = ev.Data as T // where T is the known concrete type that you've set
    if(dt == null)
    {
        // ... error handling: what will you do if you find an unexpected type?
    }
    else
    {
        return dt.itemId;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use pattern matching here also:  `if(ev.Data is T dt) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

[MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventgrid.models.eventgridevent.data?view=azure-dotnet) imply that data for `data` property is stored in JSON format.
In that case  - in addition to dynamics - one could also go with Newtonsoft to get the value of `itemId`:

```
JToken itemIdToken = JObject.Parse((string)event.Data)["itemId"];
```